# FLEX: add stroke programmatically in Actionscript

Tags: apache-flex

how can I assign the stroke to my LineSeries, programmatically in Actionscript ?

```
<mx:LineSeries stroke="{new Stroke(0xCC33CC, 2)}"  />
```

How is it in Actionscript ?

LineSeries.stroke doesn't exist

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lineStroke "property" of a charting series, such as LineSeries is not actually a property but a style, therefore it needs to be set via either mxml, css, or a call to setStyle. So you could potentially call from actionscript:

```
myLineSeries.setStyle("lineStroke", myStroke);
```

However, it's best to limit your calls to setStyle() as it's an expensive call, so I'd try to use css or mxml if at all possible.

Comment: ok cool, I've just noticed that Flex assign random colors to my lines, so I don't need to do anything :)

Comment: Yep, as far as styles go, there's nearly always a default.

Answer (score 0):

It would be something like this:

```
var s:Sprite = new Sprite();
s.graphics.lineStyle(2, 0xCC33CC); // define your line style
s.graphics.moveTo(new Point(whatever, whatever)); // move to origin
s.graphics.lineTo(new Point(whatever2, whatever2)); // draw line to target
s.graphics.lineStyle(); // this just clears the linestyle.
```

Look into the Graphics class for more information.

Comment: ...though there might be a way more specific to LineSeries, which I've never seen before.

Comment: Sorry but this is drawing a line right ? I have to apply the stroke all along the lines of my LineSeries, not just one line. Anyway, isn't there a easier solution ? I actually need to do programatically because I don't know how many LineSeries I'm going to have...

Comment: Hmm, okay, I see your point. I'm not sure if you can do a stroke specifically like that - I think as far as AS3 is concerned, strokes just become lines like this in the graphics class. I could be wrong about that, though. I'll check back later to see if anyone else is able to help.

Comment: The LineSeries stroke is completely different.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Was completely unaware of that, all of the strokes/fills I've worked with have been done through the graphics class. Thanks for the education!